# Successive Differentiation of $\mathrm{e}^{g(t)}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

I am trying to find the closed for solution for $A_n$. Assume $A_0 = g'(t)$, $A_1 = g'(t)$, and

$$\dfrac{d^n}{dt^n}\left[e^{g(t)}\right] = A_n e^{g(t)}$$

The problem has a recursive relationship of

$$A_n = \left[A_{n-2}+\dfrac{d}{dt}\right] A_{n-1}$$

which is similar to Hermite polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula):
$$
{d^n \over dx^n} f(g(x))
=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,m_2!\,\cdots\,m_n!}
f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{g^{(j)}(x)}{j!}\right)^{m_j}
$$
where the sum is over all $(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n)$ such that
$$
1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+3\cdot m_3+\cdots+n\cdot m_n=n
$$
With $f=\exp$, this becomes
$$
{d^n \over dx^n} e^{g(x)}
=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,m_2!\,\cdots\,m_n!}
e^{g(x)}
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{g^{(j)}(x)}{j!}\right)^{m_j}
$$

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it still requires you to evaluate the derivative $g^{j}(x)$ for $j>1$. Therefore further simplification should be possible using the aforementioned recursion formula. I have noticed that the terms relate to the Fibonacci numbers. Still unsure of the exact relationship. Thanks so far!

Comment: I think this does it. Thanks!

Comment: you were right. disregard last message

Answer (score 0):

Generating function
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k(x)\frac{t^k}{k!} = e^{g(x+t)-g(x)}
$$
obtained from Taylor's theorem.

Take the rest of the Wikipedia page [Hermite Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) and see what else you can imitate.